# tcp_input [C5.1:3] flags=[R.] seq=2934102331

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tcp, tcpclient

My console prints this randomly multiple times, where do i begin looking where the issue originates? The app works fine apart from this print appearing?

```
tcp_input [C5.1:3] flags=[R.] seq=2934102331, ack=920253567, win=1024 state=LAST_ACK rcv_nxt=2934102331, snd_una=920253536
2020-04-11 10:50:07.592057+0100
```

Comment: It could just be one of your pods/libraries logging an event to the console. Does your project include anything that uses tcp?

Comment: So it’s not necessarily a bad log? I use AlmoFire for images downloaded from Web

Comment: Yes, not necessarily a bad log. It’s quite some time since I’ve used Alamofire but I seem to remember that when you get a real error, you can’t miss it. I couldn’t find any info at all on the R. flag I’m afraid and although I wouldn’t advise complacency with regard to log messages it’s not unusual for 3rd party code to be quite verbose with their reports. Sorry couldn’t be of any real help.

Comment: I am using Almofire, I got the same message .. in the same time I do not see any errors in the app